# Want To try Different Linux Distros

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, partitioning, live-usb

Presently i am having windows 10, laptop with i3-processor with

c:80  gb(main windows partition)
d:100  gb(windows partition) 
e:220  gb(want to install LINUX DISTROS HERE)

**note:** i want to install in e drive, and with dual boot( or triple boot config if possible with diff linux distros)

as specified, i want to **install** and  **uninstall**, so that i can try various linux distros, so in that process, i want to know steps, if any exists, so that after i install linux my linux files and folders(if i work for some time on any linux distro, dont want them to be affected, after i format that linux distro)..

**its like saying, installing diffrent roms on my android phone, but my  files in storage remain same as they are previously**

i want to replicate this it to linux also

please provide any steps

Comment: Why not just use a VM?

Comment: @edwinksl does  that satisfy my use case  perfectly ?

Comment: I aggree to virtualization. VirtualBox might be a good starting point. But regarding the user files, you should create a separate file system on that "E" and mount to those testing VMs as a /home directory for example. It can be achieved via "share folder" feature of VirtualBox. This can be a good starting point: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OjBQC81oXqc

Answer (score 3):

just try all the distros you want on virtualbox, and when you decide what distro and flavor you like you'll find tons of tutorials here and on the internet about how to dual boot.

Answer (score 2):

There are indeed various ways you can do this, but if you just want to play around than a virtual machine is the best option. This way you can easily install many OSes at once and if you are done with one (or screw up) you can easily delete or reset it with no harm done to your real system. You don't even need to do anything to your current Windows installation to make it work.

You can download the software needed [on the official VirtualBox website](http://www.virtualbox.org).

Comment: Or better yet, instead of downloading and installing virtualbox manually, just install it throuh the Ubuntu software repositories: `sudo apt install virtualbox`

Comment: Yes, but he said he currently has Windows 10 installed so apt is not an option :p

Answer (score 0):

VM is the best option for testing but i would always prefer real installation on HDD(SSD in my case) so i can test actual performance. The only issue is that you have to fix GRUB every time you delete the partition.

Comment: can i fix grub with easybcd from windows, and do i have to fix grub if i am using two linux distros and one windows, and i want to remove or uninstall one linux distro....then, what i have to do....?

Comment: Depends if you install bootloader on different partitions and whos bootloader is closer to beggining of space. if you have each bootloader installed in root partition, system will boot the next closest. If it is a linux GRUB its ok but depends on your installation. If you have a separate partition for win bootloader and to boot linux you must override the windows one. Then if you delete partition with linux, nothing will boot. I am using different disks(not partitions) to fix this issue. I boot second disc for tests and first for linux/win boot.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting a partition too often is not very healthy for the hard drive. An HDD can indeed take a massive amount of I/O operations before starting to lose sectors but a format is still a "nail in the coffin" (maybe a smaller one, but it still is).

I'd recommend using virtual machines for testing and using a real folder on your harddisk as your /home directory in the VM.

If you really want to actually install all those distros, then you will have to have two partitions: one for your /home and one for everything else - also don't bother with a swap partition, but do keep in mind that you'll need it when you install your distro of choice once and for all, that is if you want a "performance boost" (the size of the swap partition varies depending on how much RAM you have; If you're not familiar with this concept then I can help you with that too).
By having those partitions, whenever you want to try a new distro, you only have to format the root partition and not /home , where all your personal data and configurations are stored... which brings us to another problem.

Problems:
/home stores all your personal configurations, that means they will persist to the next distro you try, and that can be a problem if that distro has different versions of your previous software (It shouldn't be a problem if they are newer, but if they are older it can be), meaning that your configurations may not be compatible with the new format. It will also accumulate a lot of bloat if you go through very different DEs (GTK-based, KDE-based, etc) and different software.
This can be easily overcome by manually deleting everything in your /home folder except for the folder branches that you want to keep (most of the times you will want to delete all hidden (dotted) files/folders - but not always, e.g: Steam games/saves; browser profiles/history, etc)